# how to get response using node.js from server

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am new in node.js .I already got response using ajax from this url :

```
http://ip.jsontest.com/
```

I download the node. js and make simple program like "hello word". I make a js insert in node dir and rum from command node hello.js.

So same way how I will get response using this url http://ip.jsontest.com/ using node.js

Comment: See http request doc http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you want to make a request to a url and get the result.

You could use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, these are the steps you might want to follow:

1. if you haven't done this yet run `npm init`, press enter to each question if you're not sure
2. run `npm install --save request`, so you get the request module and save it into the package.json file create at step 1
3. write the following in your code

   ```
   var request = require('request');
   request('http://ip.jsontest.com', function(error, response, body) {
     // body in your case is the JSON containing the IP address of the caller
   });
   ```

Note that this is an asynchronous call, so you have to deal with the answer in the call back function, wchich is the second argument of `request`.

Comment: npm init ? what is this

Comment: npm is the executable that lets you manage your node appliation, the `init` command lets you create a basic package.json file, which holds the configuration.